# OpenCV OpenCL: Convert Mat to Bitmap in JNI Layer for Android

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, opencl

There are several posts about converting Mat to Bitmap using the Utils.matToBitmap() function. But I'm assuming this function can only be called in the Java layer after importing the Utils class.

I want to transfer the data to a memory address pointed to by  uint32_t* bmpContent; in the code below.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_nod_nodcv_NodCVActivity_runfilter(
    JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject outBmp, jbyteArray inData,
    jint width, jint height, jint choice, jint filter)
{
    int outsz = width*height;
    int insz = outsz + outsz/2;
    AndroidBitmapInfo bmpInfo;

    if (AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, outBmp, &bmpInfo) < 0) {
        throwJavaException(env,"gaussianBlur","Error retrieving bitmap meta data");
        return;
    }
    if (bmpInfo.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        throwJavaException(env,"gaussianBlur","Expecting RGBA_8888 format");
        return;
    }
    uint32_t* bmpContent;
    if (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, outBmp,(void**)&bmpContent) < 0) {
        throwJavaException(env,"gaussianBlur","Unable to lock bitmap pixels");
        return;
    }

    //This function runs the kernel on the inData and gives a matrix
    tester(env, clazz, bmpContent, outsz, inData, insz, width, height);

    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, outBmp);
}
```

This is roughly what happens in the tester function:

```
jbyte*  b_mat  = env->GetByteArrayElements(inData, 0);
cv::Mat mdata(h, w, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)b_mat); 
cv::Mat mat_src = imdecode(mdata,1); 

cv::UMat umat_src = mat_src.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_READ, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);
cv::UMat umat_dst (mat_src.size(), mat_src.type(), cv::ACCESS_WRITE, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);

kernel.args(cv::ocl::KernelArg::ReadOnlyNoSize(umat_src), cv::ocl::KernelArg::ReadWrite(umat_dst));

size_t globalThreads[3] = {static_cast<unsigned int>(mat_src.cols), static_cast<unsigned int>(mat_src.rows), 1 };

bool success = kernel.run(3, globalThreads, NULL, true);

cv::Mat mat_dst = umat_dst.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);
```

mat_dst holds the results I need and that I need to display on my phone. 
How can I do that?

I'm assuming I'll need to copy the data from mat_dst to the bmpContent place, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to call this method from the JNI layer, you could simply use the OpenCV's original C++ implementation [Here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp).
An example code would be like:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <android/bitmap.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

// using namespace cv;


void MatToBitmap2 (JNIEnv * env, cv::Mat src, jobject bitmap, bool needPremultiplyAlpha)
{
    AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
    void*              pixels = 0;
    try {
        // LOGD("nMatToBitmap");
        CV_Assert( AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) >= 0 );
        CV_Assert( info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 ||
                   info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565 );
        CV_Assert( src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols );
        CV_Assert( src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4 );
        CV_Assert( AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0 );
        CV_Assert( pixels );
        if( info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 )
        {
            cv::Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
            if(src.type() == CV_8UC1)
            {
                cvtColor(src, tmp, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
            } else if(src.type() == CV_8UC3){
                cvtColor(src, tmp, cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
            } else if(src.type() == CV_8UC4){
                if(needPremultiplyAlpha) cvtColor(src, tmp, cv::COLOR_RGBA2mRGBA);
                else src.copyTo(tmp);
            }
        } else {
            // info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565
            cv::Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC2, pixels);
            if(src.type() == CV_8UC1)
            {
                cvtColor(src, tmp, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR565);
            } else if(src.type() == CV_8UC3){
                cvtColor(src, tmp, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR565);
            } else if(src.type() == CV_8UC4){
                cvtColor(src, tmp, cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR565);
            }
        }
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        return;
    } catch(const cv::Exception& e) {
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, e.what());
        return;
    } catch (...) {
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, "Unknown exception in JNI code {nMatToBitmap}");
        return;
    }
}
```

The function was directly adopted from the OpenCV sources and contains some extra checks for different formats. You could just strip the checks out if you knew what matrix format you're going to use.

> mat_dst holds the results I need and that I need to display on my phone. How can I do that?

You can call something like:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_your_package_MainActivity_DoStuff(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                               jobject bitmap) {
// Do your stuff with mat_dst.

    try {
        MatToBitmap2(env, mat_dst, bitmap, false);
    }
    catch(const cv::Exception& e)
    {
        jclass je = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
        env->ThrowNew(je, e.what());
    }
}
```

and define it in the Java side like:

```
public native void DoStuff(Bitmap bitmap);
```

You don't need to return anything back to java side as the Bitmap class would be reference type and the MatToBitmap2 method would already take care of locking and unlocking pixels buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert your Mat to Bitmap.

```
jclass java_bitmap_class = (jclass)env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(java_bitmap_class, "getConfig", "()Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
jobject bitmap_config = env->CallObjectMethod(bitmap, mid);
jobject _bitmap = mat_to_bitmap(env,dst,false,bitmap_config);

AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
return _bitmap;
```